# PHP 7 Fatal error: static::class cannot be used for compile-time class name resolution

Tags: php, php-7

Current Travis-CI PHP7 builds throw the following error when executing the following code:

> PHP 7 Fatal error: static::class cannot be used for compile-time class name resolution

```
trait EloquentValidatingTrait
{
    // Some declarations skipped
/**
 * Eloquent will call this on model boot
 */
public static function bootEloquentValidatingTrait()
{
    // Calling Model::saving() and asking it to execute assertIsValid() before model is saved into database
    $savingCallable = [static::class, 'saving'];
    $validationCallable = [static::class, 'assertIsValid'];
    forward_static_call($savingCallable, $validationCallable);
}
```

Is that a temporary bug or a future feature I missed? Notes below this [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class_name_scalars) says it should work (and it does in 5.5 and 5.6).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a valid question, but do you have this function inside the Model class or is this in a class that extends Model?

Comment: @CayceK This is a method of a trait, used by the model.

Comment: Would you be willing to show saving?

Comment: don't know if it could be of some use, I created this: http://3v4l.org/eEnUb to try to play with the code

Comment: This is a bug that was introduced [recently](http://3v4l.org/CpKdA). It looks like [this commit](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commitdiff;h=69b54ba926b714dff0f8b54bea385e9a278c5849) may have *accidentally* broken things.

Comment: Raised as [bug #69754](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69754) for those who want to keep track.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a PHP bug. :)

Comment: Hmm… Looks like I have introduced that mistake… will fix it later. [Also: thanks for testing PHP 7!]

Comment: This question should not have been closed. [Questions caused by toolchain bugs are **on-topic** for Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277480/2747593) Voting to re-open.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed this bug via http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commitdiff;h=1d3f77d13d2b457bdf1bc52045da4679741e65cb

The mistake was simple... I had in compile time constant resolution optimization set the mode to force succeed or die (a simple boolean to a function call). That mode is needed for static expressions (like `const FOO = static::class;` must fail).

Set that to zero and now it works fine. Just pull the newest master for a fix.

Comment: Thanks ;) That wasn't my PHP build, but Travis-CI's. So, I will wait for them to fetch newest source.